# wstransport.js:218 WebSocket connection to 'wss://chunderw-vpc-gll.twilio.com/signal' failed: Unknown reason

Tags: websocket, twilio

I'm getting this error while integrating Twilio task router. on localhost, so I thought might be its https error so I tried through Heroku but still getting the same error.

Comment: A failed web socket connection may be to do with your network connection, but it could also be permissions. What is the code you are using to generate the access token to authorise your user to TaskRouter?

Comment: @philnash I'm using API to generate access token using this access token I'm able to do video audio call but for task router only I'm getting this issue

Comment: Ok, so what is the code you are using to generate the Access Token?